# Determine drag proxy when using itemRenderer on DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, adobe, air

I'm using default drag/drop on Flex DataGrid, however, the dataGrid itself has an itemrenderer.
Looks like:

```
 public class FlashFileDataGridRenderer extends Label{
    public function FlashFileDataGridRenderer(){
      super();
    }
override protected function updateDisplayList (unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    this.setStyle("paddingLeft", "3");
        if (data instanceof FlashEntryBean) {
   if ((data.cutFlag)) {
    setStyle("color", "#AAAAAA");
   }
   else 
    setStyle("color", "#000000");
    }
```

That's applied to all items in the datagrid. This no longer shows the proxy with lower alpha when being dragged. I want to be able to retain that style, how can I determine if this particular item is being applied itemrenderer. I am thinking if I can determine if the object is a proxy, then fade the text myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the setStyle calls to the overriden set data method

```
override public function set data(t:Object):void
{
  super.data = t;
  if (data instanceof FlashEntryBean) {
    if (data.cutFlag) 
      setStyle("color", "#AAAAAA");
    else 
      setStyle("color", "#000000");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which SDK version you're using but in 3.5 it certainly does retain grayish text color in dragged proxy.

Comment: When you have customize itemrenderer on the item being dragged, it'll have the same style as the one in itemrenderer specified, not greyish. That's the issue here.